# Como paginar en php

Tags: php

Buenas, tengo un listado de una base de datos con el modelo vista controlador y no se como paginarlo

**view_listaUsuarios**

```
<div id="cuadro">
    <div id="titulo">
        <h1>Registros</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="centro">
            <td>Usuario</td>
            <td>Contraseña</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>1º Apellido</td>
            <td>2º Apellido</td>
            <td>DNI</td>
            <td>Dirección</td>
            <td>Población</td>
            <td>Código Postal</td>
            <td>Provincia</td>
            <td>Teléfono</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Web</td>
            <td>Blog</td>
            <td>Twitter</td>
            <td>Fecha de registro</td>            
        </tr>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($usuarios as $user)
        {

        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user['usuario'];?></td>    
        <td><?php echo $user['contraseña'];?></td>   
        <td><?php echo $user['nombre'];?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $user['apellido1'];?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $user['apellido2'];?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $user['dni'];?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $user['direccion'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['poblacion'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['CPostal'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['provincia'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['telefono'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['email'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['web'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['blog'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['twitter'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['fecha'];?></td> 
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**ctrl_listaUsuarios**

```
   include_once (MODEL_PATH.'model_usuario.php');

    $usuarios = listaUsuarios();
    include (VIEW_PATH.'view_listarUsuarios.php');
```

**model_usuario**

```
   include_once (MODEL_PATH.'claseBD.php');

function insertaUsuario($valores){
    try{
        $sentencia = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, contraseña, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni,direccion, '
                . 'poblacion, CPostal, provincia,telefono, email, web, blog, twitter)'
                . ' VALUES ("'.$valores['usuario'].'","'.$valores['pass'].'","'.$valores['nombre'].'","'.$valores['apellido1'].'","'.$valores['apellido2'].'",'
                . '"'.$valores['dni'].'","'.$valores['direccion'].'","'.$valores['poblacion'].'","'.$valores['CPostal'].'","'.$valores['provincia'].'","'.$valores['telefono'].'",'
                . '"'.$valores['email'].'","'.$valores['web'].'","'.$valores['blog'].'","'.$valores['twitter'].'","'.$valores['tipo'].'")';
        $Db=db::getInstance();
        $Db->Ejecutar($sentencia);    

    } catch (PDOexception $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
function listaUsuarios(){
    try{
        $sentencia='SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY fecha DESC';
        $Db=db::getInstance();
        $listado=$Db->Ejecutar($sentencia);
        return $listado;
    } catch (PDOexception $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
function borraUsuario($usuario){
    try{
        $sentencia = 'DELETE  FROM usuarios WHERE usuario =".$usuario."';
        $Db=db::getInstance();
        $listado=$Db->Ejecutar($sentencia);
    } catch (PDOexception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque no lo haces con dataTable

Comment: No se usar dataTable. Estoy aprendiendo PHP en el grado superior de desarrollo de aplicaciones web y necesito añadirle algunas cosas como esta a la práctica para aprobar

Comment: Si no usas datatable, entonces debes hacerlo con javascript o ajax y generar peticiones por página o generar algún tipo de div oculto con los rows cargados de BD y luego ocultarlos y mostrarlos con DOM de html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar dataTable debe agregar los archivos **jquery-1.12.4.min.js** también **jquery.dataTables.min.js** y **jquery.dataTables.min.css** y los referencia.

Luego agregas el **script**, puede ser como este:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable({  
                         
    "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
      //"info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_ / Mostrados: _START_ de _END_ ",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando: _START_ de _END_ - Total registros: _TOTAL_ ",
    "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
    "infoFiltered": "(filtrada de _MAX_ registros)",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros coincidentes",
    "paginate": {
    "next": "Siguiente",
    "previous": "Anterior"
  },
}
//linea 137 camniar el valor de inicio del select jquery.dataTables.min.js
});
});
</script>
```

Donde **#myTable** es el nombre del id de su tabla y le agregas las clases para que funcione correctamente. Por ejemplo al crear la tabla sería algo así:

```html
 <table id="myTable" class="compact display nowrap cell-border dataTable table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
 ....
 ....
 ....
 </table>
```

Y al terminar tendrá una tabla con campo de búsqueda , paginación y un select con la opción de los registros que quiere mostrar por página. Espero haber podido ayudar a lo que necesita.